# javascript not considering contextual JSON data

Tags: javascript

The following javascript is not reacting to the `polygonSeries.data` as expected with the given fill pattern.

```
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
chart.geodata = am4geodata_GBLow;
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.data = [{"id:": "GB-UKI",  "selected": true}];
polygonSeries.applyOnClones = true;

var polygonTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
polygonTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
polygonTemplate.fill = am4core.color("#74B266");

var hs = polygonTemplate.states.create("hover");
hs.properties.fill = am4core.color("#367B25");
polygonTemplate.adapter.add("fill", function (fill, target) {
  if (target.dataItem.dataContext && target.dataItem.dataContext.selected) {
    var pattern = new am4core.LinePattern();
    pattern.width = 10;
    pattern.height = 10;
    pattern.stroke = am4core.color("#367B25");
    pattern.strokeWidth = 1;
    pattern.rotation = 45;
    return pattern;
  }
  return fill;
});
polygonTemplate.adapter.add("stroke", function(fill, target) {
  if (target.dataItem.dataContext && target.dataItem.dataContext.selected) {
    return am4core.color("#367B25");
  }
  return fill;
});
```

The data is expected to be in JSON form and it [validates](http://jsonlint.com) properly. The browser debugging console shows no errors. The chart geodata is in JSON and is valid. the relevant snippet for this case:

```
[...],"properties":{"name":"Greater London","id":"GB-UKI","TYPE":"England","CNTRY":"United Kingdom"},"id":"GB-UKI"},
```

In fact, the script continues

```
polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on("hit", function (ev) {
  chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target);
});
polygonTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";
polygonTemplate.url = "https://domain.rocks/go/regions";
polygonTemplate.adapter.add("url", function(url, target) {
   return url + "?region_id=" + target.dataItem.dataContext.id;
})
```

and reacts properly using the same dataContext id as that being invoked for the selected item.  Why is this conditional statement on the dataContext not firing?

Comment: _Relevant snippet_ of JSON data contains not a JSON.

Comment: true.  But the relevance of the whole file is moot.  The JSON is being recognised (was also validated) and is being fired by the `polygonTemplate.adapter.add("url"` function. It was just to show the name and id in source.